# JMeter Unable to connect AWS RDS getting error java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

Tags: jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, database-testing

I have to connect my JMeter script to AWS RDS database.
When I am running my test with the below JDBC Connection configuration it is showing this error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.)
```

JDBC Connection configuration:

[image: JDBC Connect Config screenshot]

JDBC Request:

[image: JDBC Request screenshot]

Response Error Message:

[image: Error Message screenshot]

I already added mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar file in Jmeter's /lib folder, but it didn't help.

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 0):

From JMeter perspective your connection configuration looks OK, the problem is on RDS end. The only thing you can do from JMeter is [try increasing JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the MySQL Connector/J in order to get more troubleshooting information in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), the line to be added to JMeter's *log4j2.xml* file is:

```
<Logger name="com.mysql.jdbc" level="debug" />
```

Troubleshooting steps for RDS/AWS/MySQL:

- Make sure to open port `3306` in the [RDS Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html)
- Make sure to whitelist the external IP address of your JMeter machine(s) in the [VPC Security Group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html) (or use wildcard like `0.0.0.0/0` so anyone will be able to connect)
- Make sure that your MySQL instance is bound to the [public IP address](https://medium.com/@datapath_io/elastic-ip-static-ip-public-ip-whats-the-difference-8e36ac92b8e7) or listening on all interfaces, see [`bind-address` directive](https://serversforhackers.com/c/mysql-network-security)